# Can't build in Android Studio 2.2.1

Tags: android-studio-2.2

I just installed Android Studio 2.2.1 tonight.

I am using Linux Ubuntu 14.04 32 bit os

JAVA_HOME is jdk1.8.0_60. It is set as Android Studio boot JDL and that works fine.

However when I build my "hello world" project I get:

```
Gradle sync failed: Process 'command '/usr/local/android-studio/jre/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

I have been reading that this has to do with a large build.gradle file and that I should do this:

```
set multiDexEnabled true
```

But this is a minimal brand-new OOTB build.gradle file. I have done nothing to it.

Oh and my settings in

```
Project Structure -> Android SDK Location
```

is ~/Android/Sdk. In that directory I have:

```
ls ~/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-24/
android.jar            data            package.xml     source.properties
android-stubs-src.jar  framework.aidl  sdk.properties  templates
build.prop             optional        skins           uiautomator.jar
```

So I am at a loss. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: What's the JDK location in `Project Structure -> JDK Location`?

Comment: That was the problem @iRuth. I had to go into ~/.AndroidStudio2.2/config/studio.jdk and update it to usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_60 (my JAVA_HOME) then, in Project Structure, I change JDK to the one in /usr/local/java